# jquery scaleIn instead of fadeIn?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, transition

I have a simple div element item that i'm dynamically placing  inside another div.

```
var item = document.createElement('div')
$(item).hide().appendTo($('#container')).fadeIn()
```

This works great, but I want to replace the fadeIn effect with a scaleIn effect i.e item appears on screen with scale 0 and then animates to scale 1.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery UI to create an effect like this, below is an example.

HTML:

```
<p>Click the Buttons!</p>

      <button id = "hide"> Hide </button>
      <button id = "show"> Show</button> 

      <div class = "target">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
p {
  width:200px; border:1px solid green;
}

div{ 
   width:100px; height:100px; background:red;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $("#hide").click(function(){
      $(".target").hide( "scale", {percent: 200, direction: 'horizontal'}, 2000 );
   });

   $("#show").click(function(){
      $(".target").show( "scale", {percent: 200, direction: 'vertical' }, 2000 );
   });

});
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/NGLNaJ)

Read more here at [jQueryUI Scale](https://api.jqueryui.com/scale-effect/)